# Use a Field value in a Query (Seblod Query plugin)

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I'm using the **Query plugin** that lets me create a Query field on my List & Search.

I have a hidden field with ID '**id_number**' which I'm trying to use in my query. When I check the Page Source(Ctrl+U on Chrome), the hidden field has the correct value of id_number which is '22865'.

The part of my Query is-

```
WHERE [MATCH]p.pid||$cck->getValue('id_number')[/MATCH] AND (ban_reason in ("", "active"))
```

When I print this query out using the Debugger, the Query is using the literal value and querying the above as-

```
(p.pid LIKE '%$cck->getValue(\'id\_number\')%') ....and not like (p.pid LIKE '%22865%')
```

I also tried using **$fields['id_number']->value** but it still queries it incorrectly.

Should I not use $cck->getValue('id_number') to get the value of the hidden field in the query? Or is there something other than this that I need to use?

Comment: I haven't used Seblod, but your stuff looks good to me. https://www.seblod.com/resources/tutorials/using-the-search-query-field-plugin  Maybe try [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Yes this baffles me as well. I have used the $uri variable before to pick up form fields and use them in the query, but for this I want the value of a hidden field. I have posted on Joomla SE also, thanks.